# Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Widget fields not rendering in Elementor Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

i work with ACF Pro and Elementor Plugin to Build My Web Page On Wordpress
but when i add ACF Field to any Wordpress Widget Elemntor Can not Rendering The ACF Field And Show it on elementor Live Editor.
.
.
how can i fix this ?

Comment: which version of elementor you are using?

Comment: I think it’s a bit different this issue relates to compatibility with ACF, in order to build a new widget for Elementor under WordPress widgets, but the other issue is for adding a custom field into existing widgets.

Comment: @VasimVanzara i use 2.0.8 - i can add acf field to wordpress widget and my pure wordpress widget without acf field it works in elementor but if i have acf field in any wordpress widget that field not showing in live elementor editor

Answer (score 1):

show ACF fields in Elementor by adding:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'in_widget_form', array( &$instance, null, $this->get_settings( 'wp' )  ) );
```

right after `$instance->form()` in:

elementor/includes/widgets/wordpress.php

```
$instance->form( $this->get_settings( 'wp' ) );
```

Comment: This code is not work for uploader and repeater , do you have any solution ?